# Designing a system to handle long running API scraping job

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, design-patterns, architecture

I'm looking to design an application which makes thousands of API calls, aggregates the data and then returns it to the client in an asynchronous manner. The calls are GET with different query parameters.

Is there a known design pattern to solve this problem? The challenge here is to make the application fault tolerant so that if it crashes, or a new deployment is triggered, the ongoing requests are not lost due to application restart.

Here's what my current application looks like:
[image]

Comment: You just have to regular record the progress of your API calls to persistent storage so if your server stops or crashes and then restarts for any reason, you can just pick up where you previously left off.  When the server restarts, it checks the file store to see where it should pick up again.  Depending upon the amount of data that must be stored, this can either be just a JSON file you regularly rewrite to disk or it can be info stored in a database.  Either way, just keep the progress state up-to-date on disk and you can always restart where you last left off when the server restarts.

Comment: Just don't retain important state only in memory, put that state regularly onto disk and your server can then be resilient and able to pick up where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

As jfriend00 stated in the comments to your question, the key is to persist your results, e.g. in DynamoDB.

To process your workload in a performant and fault-tolerant way, you should start the process by writing your API request jobs into an SQS queue and have the worker pull items one by one from the queue, process them and then write  to the database.

(If you don’t know SQS, please read the docs thoroughly; it is the right tool for the job, but you need to be aware of caveats such as visibility timeouts, ordering and duplications.)

If you want to take it one step further, you could look into applying the [fan-out pattern with SNS/SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/) and have items processed by Lambdas rather than an EC2 instance. This will massively accellerate the whole thing and probably even be more cost-efficient, especially when considering the Lambda free tier.